# How to change the base reference year in R

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by, transformation, mutate

I have a very large dataframe containing monthly price indices of 400 items, across 20 years. For my analysis, I need to chain the indices across years to provide a consistent base reference period. Essentially, the January index is calculated relative to the previous January. This picture shows a simple example of how you’d go about chaining, highlighting the January months. The item_index column shows the original index and the new-index column shows the desired index. In this example, the new_index 2018:01=D14xE13/100, 2018:02=D15xE14/100 and ..., until 2019:01=D26xE25/100 and so on so forth. I really appreciate if you could help me to write the code in an efficient way.

I think the answer might involve a combination of group_by and first, but not quite sure. Here is a piece of code that I did following an answer from Mark below, but not giving me what I want:

```
  df <- df %>% 
  mutate(index_date = ym(index_date)) %>% 
  mutate(out = ifelse(year(index_date)==2017, item_index, item_index * first(new_index) / 100), .by = base_date)
```

[image]

```
df <- structure(list(index_date = structure(c(17167, 17198, 17226, 
17257, 17287, 17318, 17348, 17379, 17410, 17440, 17471, 17501, 
17532, 17563, 17591, 17622, 17652, 17683, 17713, 17744, 17775, 
17805, 17836, 17866, 17897, 17928, 17956, 17987, 18017, 18048, 
18078, 18109, 18140, 18170, 18201, 18231, 18262, 18293, 18322, 
18353, 18383, 18414, 18444, 18475, 18506, 18536, 18567, 18597
), class = "Date"), item_id = c(310405, 310405, 310405, 310405, 
310405, 310405, 310405, 310405, 310405, 310405, 310405, 310405, 
310405, 310405, 310405, 310405, 310405, 310405, 310405, 310405, 
310405, 310405, 310405, 310405, 310405, 310405, 310405, 310405, 
310405, 310405, 310405, 310405, 310405, 310405, 310405, 310405, 
310405, 310405, 310405, 310405, 310405, 310405, 310405, 310405, 
310405, 310405, 310405, 310405), base_date = c(201601, 201701, 
201701, 201701, 201701, 201701, 201701, 201701, 201701, 201701, 
201701, 201701, 201712, 201801, 201801, 201801, 201801, 201801, 
201801, 201801, 201801, 201801, 201801, 201801, 201812, 201901, 
201901, 201901, 201901, 201901, 201901, 201901, 201901, 201901, 
201901, 201901, 201912, 202001, 202001, 202001, 202001, 202001, 
202001, 202001, 202001, 202001, 202001, 202001), item_index = c(98.258, 
99.397, 99.947, 96.607, 98.417, 102.261, 101.719, 102.018, 99.88, 
100.447, 95.759, 95.334, 103.718, 100.758, 97.906, 93.305, 98.987, 
96.349, 93.586, 100.091, 97.8, 95.633, 93.759, 92.471, 101.023, 
97.782, 99.697, 94.008, 97.942, 98.874, 95.886, 99.385, 97.472, 
95.792, 98.138, 95.18, 101.098, 99.525, 98.032, 99.571, 96.245, 
93.816, 95.445, 99.266, 97.008, 99.151, 96.824, 92.32), new_index = c(98.258, 
99.397, 99.947, 96.607, 98.417, 102.261, 101.719, 102.018, 99.88, 
100.447, 95.759, 95.334, 98.87851812, 99.6280172873496, 96.8080019505672, 
92.258601331866, 97.8768787314444, 95.2684634234388, 92.5364499677832, 
98.9684975714892, 96.70319072136, 94.5604932336996, 92.7075098041308, 
91.4339544907452, 92.3693238451855, 90.3205722422993, 92.0894447939346, 
86.834553960382, 90.4683631604516, 91.3292452586887, 88.5692498621946, 
91.8012525035377, 90.0342273383792, 88.4824226977801, 90.6494070351882, 
87.9171224358476, 88.8824524401932, 88.4602607911023, 87.1332457761702, 
88.5011467192248, 85.544916351064, 83.3859615812917, 84.8338567315424, 
88.2300552392822, 86.2230894631826, 88.127840418976, 86.0595457506927, 
82.0562800927864)), row.names = c(NA, -48L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: please share what you have tried so far

Comment: @Mark, sorry it was a typo. It should be new_index 2018:01=D14xE13/100

Comment: thanks! one more question. When 2017:01 looks back to the previous row (for the E column), what does it use? 0 I assume?

Comment: For the first year (hear 2017) the new_indice = item_index.

Comment: @Mike I followed Mark's answer here, but it's not giving me exactly what I want: df <- df %>% 
  mutate(index_date = ym(index_date)) %>% 
  mutate(out = ifelse(year(index_date), item_index, item_index * first(new_index) / 100), .by = base_date)